# SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression while creating a route with route params

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a class for creating a route and another class for bundling routes and then adding them to an express app or express router. The problem is in my route class, when I create a route with route params and then try to connect it to an express app (example: /api/:myparam => myparam is a route parameter in this case)
RegExp throws a SyntaxError. I will show you what happens for each route when they're being connected to an express app:

```
// "this" is the route
// "this.path" is a string
// "this.type" is "GET" or "POST"
// "RouteFunction" type is a normal express route function=

connectToRouter(router: Router | Express, routerPath: string, globalMiddlewares?: RouteFunction[]) {
        router[this.type.toLowerCase()](
            path.join(routerPath, this.path),
            ...globalMiddlewares,
            ...this.middlewares,
            this.functions,
        );
    }
```

Basically in here `router` is the express app and by doing `router[type.toLoweCase()]` if the type was `GET` I'm accessing `router.get`.

If I add a route by doing `app.get` I'm able to add route params to my string (`app.get("/:myparam", func)`) but when I do it the way I showed you I get a syntax error.

Error:

```
  return new RegExp(path, flags);
         ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\api\v1\discounts\store\storeName\(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/: Unmatched ')'
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at pathtoRegexp (C:\Users\User\Documents\wowl-discount-tracker\discount-tracker\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:128:10)
    at new Layer (C:\Users\User\Documents\wowl-discount-tracker\discount-tracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:45:17)
    at Function.route (C:\Users\User\Documents\wowl-discount-tracker\discount-tracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:505:15)
    at app.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\User\Documents\wowl-discount-tracker\discount-tracker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:498:30)
    at Route.connectToRouter (file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/wowl-discount-tracker/discount-tracker/dist/lib/route/route.js:5:40)
    at file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/wowl-discount-tracker/discount-tracker/dist/lib/route/routeWrap.js:10:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at RouteWrap.connectToRouter (file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/wowl-discount-tracker/discount-tracker/dist/lib/route/routeWrap.js:9:21)
    at file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/wowl-discount-tracker/discount-tracker/dist/api/index.js:32:15
```

The route path I was trying to create is this:

`GET` `\api\v1\discounts\store\:storeName\` (generated by path.join)

Maybe the problem is with the backslashes generated by path.join, anyone know a way to make it normal slashes? Instead of replacing all with normal slashes ofcourse.

EDIT:
This (^) was actually true, the problem is about the backslashes. I used this simple replace function to reverse the slashes and it worked.

```js
const routePath = path.join(routerPath, this.path);
const pathWithReversedSlashes = routePath.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

If anyone has a easier way of doing this, maybe on the `path.join` side I would like to hear about it.

Comment: Those should be *slashes* not *backslashes*. `\v` and `/v` are *significantly* different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `path.join` just use template literals.

FYI - this is to do with the backslashes generated by `path.join`.

**From**:

```
path.join(routerPath, this.path)
```

**To**:

```
`${routerPath}/${this.path}`
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that's true though I will keep on using `path.join` since it's much more smarter than me adding a slash by myself. But I simply use a replace function now to replace the slashes with the reversed ones.